# How to delete a row of a Table in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView and I want to provide the functionality to user to delete the row when he slips or flicks his finger on the row. I know the editing style which provides a circular red button with -ve sign on it. But How to implement the flicking style. I saw many applications using it, so does apple provide any inbuilt delegate for it or we need to write our own controller for it.

Comment: can you tell me the method You already know? coz i wanna implement that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In order to get the swipe affect you need to implement the table view delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, this will provide access to the swipe interaction for deletion.  I typically provide an edit interaction as well for tableviews where deletion is possible since the swipe interaction tends to be a little bit hidden from users.

As an example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [tableView beginUpdates];    
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Do whatever data deletion you need to do...
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];   
  }       
  [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: withRowAnimation:YES is wrong, you should use an enum e.g. withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop

Comment: Consider changing `...UITableViewRowAnimationTop];` to `...UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`. This was done in an invalid edit (should have been a comment), so I reverted it. If this is correct, consider updating your solution accordingly.

Comment: That was me. UITableViewRowAnimationTop should be UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic to show the correct animation when deleting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost positive that there is a sample application that does this. A more concrete answer will come soon.

UPDATE: [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/index.html) gives probably exactly what you're looking for.

On topic, here is one of the sweetest provided methods:

```
// If I want to delete the next 3 cells after the one you click
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSMutableArray* indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (int i = indexPath.row + 3; i < indexPath.row + 3; i++)
  {
    [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
  }

  [tableView beginUpdates];
  [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  [tableView endUpdates];
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

I think that there is an easier way to accomplish what you want, but then again this is pretty easy. The only difficulty might be deleting yourself...just watch out for segfaults.